# D’où vient ce « l’ » dans « que l’on » ?

Tags: grammaire

Il y a une traduction pour ce « l’ » ? Ça remplace quelque chose ? C’est plutôt du langage écrit ?

[image: Le jetable que l’on garde]

Autres exemples:

- Sait-on ce *que l’on* mange ?
- Toutes ces choses *que l’on* n'ose pas dire
- On n’enseigne pas ce *que l’on* sait ou ce *que l’on* croit savoir : on n’enseigne et on ne peut enseigner que ce *que l’on* est.